# Running a script file from guide gui

Tags: matlab

I have imported a .txt file data as cell array to base workspace using import tool.

Now I have GUI created using GUIDE with push button which will run a script which utilizes the base workspace variables to create another file.

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
createfile;
```

when I run the createfile using push button its shows undefined function or variable even though that variable is in base workspace.

But when I run the same file in command window everything is fine . Any suggestions why this is happening?

Comment: Each callback (i.g. function called from the pushbutton) has its own variable workspace, add the path were your file is located in your callback and that should work.

Comment: See: [Base and Function Workspaces](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/base-and-function-workspaces.html)

Comment: so should i include that variable present in base workspace to function workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GUI has it's own workspace, therefore you have to commit the base workspace variables on GUI initialization. e.g.: `yourGUI(yourData);`

Edit the OpeningFcn of the GUI to something like this:

```
handles.InputData= varargin(1);
%only for clear arrangement
handles.InputData = handles.InputData{1, 1};
```

Feel free to rename `InputData`, but don't forget to update the handles structure

```
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Now you can access `handles.InputData` in all CallbackFunctions, but beware you have to `guidata(hObject, handles);` after each change in `handles.InputData`. Read the [documentation](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

Which function/variable is undefined? What is the name of the file and at which variable do you assign it to? My guess (literally), assuming that none of the `pushbutton1_Callback` inputs is the variable that you mentioned, would be the following:

Functions and command window do not share the same workspace. If you want something to be "seen" from your function you have to include it in the inputs.